# Suspended users are somewhat off in Users pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, account-suspension, users-page

[image]

---

That was the last page of the "Week" view. Losing 8867 rep in one week surely can't be true.

Comment: lol@ RichB.  Oh, I do miss him.

Comment: @Will, I always wondered why he didn't create another account and started over... or perhaps he did do it...

Comment: Perhaps indeed, "Juan"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suspended users will now have their interval scores set to 0 as a no-participation indicator for the period, the same way their overall reputation is set to 1 during the suspension.

When returning from a suspension, a user's reputation is recalculated, so their proper league scores for each interval will be restored. As with overall rep, a suspension doesn't in any way permanently penalize you here.

Answer (score 2):

He got hit by a rep recalc yesterday.  Since he's suspended, his rep was apparently set back to 1 instantly, so the system does think he lost 8,867 rep this week.  <strike>Suspensions are even more rare than bounties, so I doubt there will be a fix for the corner case.</strike>

Comment: If someone's rep goes from 8867 to 1, aren't they theoretically *gaining* 8866 rep in one week?

Comment: @Thomas: That looks like a steep downward slope to me.  They won't seem to be gaining that rep back until the suspension is lifted.

Comment: How does one manage to accumulate -8867 rep anyway? That takes dedicated effort at being a jerk as opposed to a single bad day.

Comment: @Thomas: -8867 isn't his total, it's how much his rep changed.